# Wifi not working on hp laptop

Tags: 10.04, laptop, hp, wifi-hardware-switch

I have both ubuntu and windows7 installed on my  `HP laptop (model no:15ro33tx)`.wifi is working fine on windows but on `ubuntu 10.04` its not working.I have a wifi key with led its not `turning ON` on ubuntu. How can i enable that?please guide me through the debugging process.

can anyone help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hardware you have, there looks to be 3 different wireless card possibilities for your machine.  I would start there, figure out which manufacturer you have and then locate the wireless driver for Linux for it.  Once you locate the driver and install it you should be able to connect to your WAP/Router and be on your way.

Comment: Thanks @Optichip checked the driver its `Ra link RT3290`.Installed the driver and its working now.Got the details from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104690). warm regards!!

Comment: Glad to hear it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Additional Drivers application, check for any drivers pertaining to STA and disable them.

Open Terminal and enter the following command:

**sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl-kernel-source**

Now, enter the following commands:

**echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist brcm80211" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

Reboot Ubuntu.

Open Terminal again and enter the following command:

**sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer**

After the package installation is complete, reboot.

Open Additional Drivers.

Enable the Broadcom STA driver.

Your Wifi should now be active and functional.